# How do I fix horizontal lines on a laptop screen and webcam not working?

Tags: laptop, webcam, lcd

I have a Asus ROG GL771JW laptop. The webcam is working for 1 second and turning off. There are horizontal lines appearing once in a while, that I can make disappear by pressing on certain parts of the back lid. I can disassemble the LCD. Is there a way to fix this without buying any part? or do I have to buy a LCD cable or a new LCD panel?
i searched similar questions online, I saw many people having the horizontal lines problem, but none of them having the webcam problem at the same time. Maybe this would help in determining how to fix that.